# Type checking not working in javascript NextJS project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, next.js, eslint

When I type invalid property name of a `const` object in jsx code, VSCode doesn't show error.
Sample code:

Index.js (misspelling property Name as nmea)

```
const formFields = {
 Name: "inputName",
 PickupAddress: "inputPickupAddress",
};

export default function FormDetails() {
 return (
      <form>
       <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          name={formFields.nmea}  {/* => property Name is misspelled as nmea but still no error in VSCode */}
        />
      </form>
}
```

However, when I hover over `formFields` object I can see its properties:

```
 const formFields: {
 Name: string;
 PickupAddress: string;
}
```

If I can see these assigned properties in an object then VSCode should also throw error if I mistype a property. 
I have also configured `ESLint` which is detecting all kind of other errors but not this one.

I know this error would've captured in TS project but how to make it work in JS project.
Do I need to add some specific eslint plugin? tsconfig/jsconfig file?

Comment: "would've captured in TS project but how to make it work in JS project" - i don't think trying to get static checking up in JS but deliberately avoiding TS (or similar projects) is a good idea. I mean, it's basically what TS and related were made for.

Comment: it is not always straight forward to port every project to TS otherwise everyone would be doing that and there won't be any scope left for 'js' project. sometimes projects are large to port, time constraint, existing CI CD configs etc.